# Testear metodo en happy case si no devuelve valor ni tiene efectos laterales

Tags: php, phpunit

Me encuentro testeando con phpunit una aplicacion, y me he encontrado un caso muy raro. Tengo un objeto con un metodo parecido al siguiente:

```
public function validar(array $array = [])
{
if(empty($array['clave'])
    throw new \Exception("no hay clave");

    // otras validaciones...

    //fin
}
```

Este metodo comprueba el array que se le pasa por parametro, y si hay algun error, lanza la excepcion correspondiente. En caso de estar correcto, el flujo sigue su curso.

Al intentar hacer el test en el caso de que todos los parametros son correctos, hago lo siguiente:

```
public function testValidarHappyCase() 
{
    $objeto = new MiClase();
    $params = [
        'clave' => 1,
        'user' => 3,
        'publicacion' => 3    
    ];
    $objeto->validar();
}
```

El problema es que, al ejecutar el phpunit, me sale esto:

```
Testing App\Tests\Clases\MiClaseTest
.R..                                                                4 / 4 (100%)

Time: 21.68 seconds, Memory: 42.50 MB

There was 1 risky test:

1) App\Tests\Clases\MiClasetest::testValidarHappyCase
This test did not perform any assertions

/zen/tests/Clases/MiClaseTest.php:41

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 5, Risky: 1.
```

Como el metodo no devuelve ningun valor, no puedo hacer algun assert con el resultado, para validar si es correcto o no. Realmente no se como testear esto.

Se me ha ocurrido que podria añadir un return 1 o algo asi, para que en el test se validara un resultado. El problema es que por especificacion de la app no puedo tocar esos objetos...

Alguien tiene alguna idea para comprobar esto?

Comment: Prueba agregando  la anotación [`@doesNotPerformAssertions`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.5/annotations.html#doesnotperformassertions). Algo así: `/**
 * @doesNotPerformAssertions
 */
public function testValidarHappyCase() 
{
    // código...
}`

Comment: perfecto!!! muchas gracias @A.Cedano. efectivamente, me acepta el test como correcto y no salta el warning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso puedes hacer uso de la anotación:

> ## [`@doesNotPerformAssertions`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.5/annotations.html#doesnotperformassertions)
>
> Prevents a test that performs no assertions from being considered
>   risky.
>
> ---
>
> Impide que una prueba que no realiza afirmaciones se considere riesgosa.

Por ejemplo:

```
/** 
  * @doesNotPerformAssertions 
  */ 
public function testValidarHappyCase() 
{ 
    // código... 
}
```